# Django ModelViewSet. How to merge two perform methods/functions?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to merge perform methods/functions? The view uses ModelViewSet. I have two functions **perform_create** and **perform_update** that do the same thing and I wondered could I merge them somehow?

**Body**

```
{
    "title": "1 Title",
    "description": "1 Description",
    "author": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

**View**

```
class ArticleView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        author = get_object_or_404(Author, id=self.request.data['author']['id'])
        return serializer.save(author=author)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        author = get_object_or_404(Author, id=self.request.data['author']['id'])
        return serializer.save(author=author)
```

**Serializers**

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the `perform_create` function as `perform_update` as well:

```
class ArticleView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        author = get_object_or_404(Author, id=self.request.data['author']['id'])
        return serializer.save(author=author)

    perform_update = perform_create
```